# 'Too many open files' error xcode

Tags: xcode, file, out-of-memory

This is quite odd. I'm not at all sure why I'm getting this error. I deleted the derived data already and I'm not else quite sure where this error is coming from.

This is the first time I've seen it. It used to show up when running my simulator and now it's showing up when running on my phone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to run `ulimit` in terminal and show result

Comment: @Arsen Oh wow. I can't even do that. I've posted the error I get when trying to even open the terminal above.

Comment: Just reboot the computer and come back :)

Comment: This can occur due to a recursion error. Also I notice there are spaces character in some of the paths, be sure they are properly escaped or quoted. In general there is less pain if spaces are avoided in file names in code bases.

Comment: @Arsen yeah a reboot sort of helped, but your solution seems to have made things go away. Woo! Thanks. Life saver.

Comment: This is probably caused by a different application, it doesn't have to be connected to Xcode at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just have reached the maximum number of open file descriptors.

You can check the limit by

```
$ ulimit
```

And change it by:

```
$ ulimit -n 6666
```

But do not forget `ulimit` changes the limit only for current session. You have to put `ulimit -n 6666` to `.bash_profile` or something like this

Comment: Hmm, running `ulimit` in Terminal says: `unlimited`. Reboot helps tho.

Answer (score 11):

Check if you have too many open simulators. I closed all the simulators and the error went away

Comment: This did it for me as well. I recently got a separate computer for work which has less RAM and probably some missing configurations. I imagine one of those two things has to do with the error.

Answer (score 4):

Check the number of file descriptors that can be opened by your shell. Most cases, default will be 256.

`ulimit -a`

To solve the 'too many open files' issue locally, increase the number of files that can be opened per shell:

`ulimit -S -n 2048 #2048 works fine, or you may put other value.`

In case it still does not resolve, system settings can be checked the following way:

`sysctl kern.maxfiles
 sysctl kern.maxfilesperproc`

If you prefer to increase the limits system wide, go for these:

`sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=20480 (or any number)
 sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=18000 (or any number)`

Use `sudo` at the beginning of the command, in case you get permission denied.

In order to make this a permanent setting, you will need to add it or change default kernal parameters in `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.

This [article](https://krypted.com/mac-os-x/maximum-files-in-mac-os-x/) explains the details.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the simulator & press quit after that error will be away.